# Time Complexity and Optimization for the Algorithm?

Tags: time-complexity, np-complete, optimization, p-vs-np

I have found a algorithm to check whether a Hamiltonian Cycle Exists in the graph or not, but not able to compute/analyse it's time complexity.

The algorithm is as follows :

1. Label all the vertices with distinct prime numbers.
2. Label all edges with weight equal to 1.
3. Now remove one vertex at a time, while removing a vertex v, if there is edge between u and v & v and w, then add a edge between u and w, with weight = weight(u->v)*weight(v->w)*label(v)
4. If at the end you end up with only one vertex with self edges and if there is a self edge that is equal to the product of all the primes of the removed vertices then there is Hamiltonian Cycle.

I have proved the algorithm is correct but unable to find it's time complexity. I think there can be much more optimization in this algorithm also, as we don't need to add those edges to the graph that whose weight divides the weight of some other already present edge.
If someone can give some optimization to this algorithm it may turn out to be polynomial, thus proving P = NP.

Comment: It seems that the number of edges (assuming you allow two edges between the same vertices with different weights) will become exponential (as there can be an edge with distinct weight for every subset of vertices). Using prime numbers just obfuscates what the algorithm is doing, namely keeping track of subsets of vertices. There's no good reason this approach has any viability and could lead to a proof of $P=NP$. Even if it did, discussion/development of scientific "breakthroughs" does not belong on a question and answer site but rather on something more like a forum.

Comment: Yeah, I too had a feeling of like the number of edges going exponential but if we can intelligently remove the unnecessary edges then the complexity might go down, also for sparse graphs this algorithm will do pretty good.

Comment: Are you assuming you can multiply large numbers in constant time?

Comment: Actually we don't need to multiply the numbers, we can just keep the set of all prime numbers to be multiplied.

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, whenever you start thinking about algorithms that use the nice prime factorization property things start breaking down. Why? You never said *how* you could generate $n$ prime numbers. That is not $\in P$, in fact that is still an open problem in mathematics, how many prime numbers are there? So even though the algorithm amy be suitable for small input sizes it is not theoretically sound.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  Generating prime numbers can be done in polynomial time.  See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Fast_deterministic_tests.

Comment: That's a primality test not generation

Comment: Look up the sieve of Eratosthenes

Comment: I know -- and you can use polynomial-time primality testing to generate primes, simply by trial and error (pick a number, test if it is prime, and if not, repeat).  In this way you can generate $n$ prime numbers in time polynomial in $n$, so this answer's claim is not correct.

Comment: No think about how large the set of integers is

Comment: Now think about what happens in the worst case randomly picking numbers

Comment: As I see it, there are only $n=|V|$ different primes needed.  If you think this is not accurate, please edit the question to give a more detailed running time analysis and justification for why it can't be done in polynomial time.

Comment: In the absolute worst case your random integer generator which you use to then test for primality  NEVER generates a prime number since Z is infinite. In order to do a runtime analysis you would need to know the distribution of primes in the integers which is something way over my head.

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: Not so much, no. And why exactly would you pick numbers totally at random? Oh wait, you do not even have RNG but PRNG. Since when prime numbers are finite? Lastly I checked it was proved there are infinite prime numbers, and even if it was counterwise, I would just use your newly invented algorithm to prescreen those that are not prime.

Comment: @user2879934 If you pick a random integer $x$, then the probability that $x$ is prime is $\Theta(1/\log x)$. In fact, you don't even need to use the (extremely efficient) method of picking random numbers and testing them as D.W. suggested. If you want to generate $n$ prime numbers, then you just need to run the Sieve of Eratosthenes in the first $\Theta(n\log n)$ numbers, which is polynomial.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden I think we are getting practice and theory confused. First of all: when you start doing run time analysis on randomized algorithms you start taking expected values of probabilities so you are talking about average case not worse case. Second of all, I totally agree and mentioned above, that you can use the sieve but as wikipedia states "There is no known useful formula that sets apart all of the prime numbers from composites.".

Comment: @TomvanderZanden You can read about the complexity of the sieve here :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes but as noted in this discussion,http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFormulas.html, the actual answer is no such generating function has been found thats why it was big news when on Jan. 25, the largest known prime number, 2^57,885,161-1, was discovered on Great Internet Mersenne Prime Search (GIMPS)

Comment: @user2879934 I agree no prime generating formula is known, but that's not what we're discussing here. Your answer is incorrect, using the Sieve of Eratosthenes will allow you to generate the primes required for the suggested algorithm in deterministic, polynomial, worst-case time. The sieve is exponential only in the *input size*, to generate $n$ distinct primes we just need to run the Sieve for integers up to $\Theta(n \log n)$. In that case the input size is $\Theta(\log{(n\log n)})$ and the running time is thus polynomial.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden okay so lets say I hand you a graph with 2^57,885,161-1 + 1 vertices how are you going to label the last vertex? (lets just pretend the largest prime number found is also the number of prime numbers that exist, meaning every number is prime up to the largest one found since I don't know how many primes have been found only the largest one to date)

Comment: @TomvanderZanden I agree that the algorithm is $\in P$ if you add the condition that the cardinality of $V <  2^{57,885,161}-1$

Comment: @user2879934 There are infinitely many prime numbers. If I had to find $2^{57,885,161-1} + 1$ distinct prime numbers that would take a lot of time (and it would be infeasible with today's technology) but it would still be possible within time polynomial in $2^{57,885,161-1} + 1$. $2^{57,885,161-1} + 1$ is such a large number that anything polynomial in it is beyond our current capabilities, though.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden That is the statement I don't agree with "but it would still be polynomial in 257,885,161−1" but we can agree to disagree

Comment: "[it] is still an open problem in mathematics, how many prime numbers are there". [No, it isn't.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem)

Comment: @TomvanderZanden that is very true, I misspoke there... there are definitely infinitely many primes..its just finding them that is non-polynomial